# Error when connecting to database Zend, MySQL, MAMP, Mac, OSX

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mamp

I have just purchased a MacBook Air and am having trouble setting up my development environment. On windows I used WAMP with fairly few problems, and on OSX I'm using MAMP.

- the windows development environment is working as needed, and I'm using an exact copy to start out on the mac
- When I visit the phpMyAdmin page I am able to log in, and make changes to the database.
- My application is based off of the **Zend Quickstart tutorial**, so I am using the error controller that comes with that (I haven't changed it)
- My application will work up until the point I call to connect to the database:

`$dbAdapter->getConnection();` results in:
"An error occurred
Application error"

As you can see there is no information about the error. Typically an error will have a code and description, whatever is causing this error is not providing any information.

Please help! Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: The answer was indeed that my virtual host was not set up correctly, and left the environment variable undefined, which caused the application to run as if in production. This caused the application to attempt to access a database that doesn't exist on my local dev env. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It seems like you are in production environment, i.e. have set `resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0`. Since your application is built on the quick start-example, you can either change your application.ini or place a .htaccess with `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"` in your public/ folder to make ZF display exceptions instead of the error page. I'm not familiar with Mac (or MAMP for that matter), so I can't help on what's wrong with your database-connection without having at least a proper error message.

Comment: did you remember to put your users into Mysql, importing the db's and tables usually will not out the users back.

Answer (score 0):

Current OSX has built in php, apache. you need to install mysql. for few months I'm using [Zend server community edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/). You may try this. its easy to install and maintainable through GUI